# IBM i (as400) DB2 retrieve and unpack value from java

Tags: java, sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to retrieve a packed value from db2 (as400). I have no experience with DB2 and completely unaware of PACK values.

Can somebody provide me **packing** or **unpacking** algorithm.

I have already tried `SELECT HEX(value) FROM.....`. This is not working...

Thanx in advance.

Comment: packed is just 4 bits for each digit.  Try casting the value to numeric or integer bigint etc where applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,

We can decrypt `<BLOB>` type value using **IBM500** *Coded character set identifiers*, in java.

```
//rsAS400.getBytes("F00001") this returns <BLOB> type value

String value = new String(rsAS400.getBytes("F00001"), "IBM500");
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do anything special.  DB2 internally stores some numbers as packed, but when it delivers those numbers to you, it unpacks them.  `select packed_numeric_column from db2_table...` will work just fine.

Comment: Well then it sounds as if the column is a BLOB.  You need to find out how the BLOB was originally populated.  DB2 itself won't be able to tell you; you need to talk to the programming team who maintain the database.

Comment: @Kandy Do you know for certain that the column is encrypted?

Comment: @ user2338816 ,return value should be a String , but it returns something called BLOB(not image blob).Thats why I think its encrypted

Comment: Why do you think it should be String?  What did the database team tell you about this column?  BLOB does NOT mean 'image' - it means binary object which could be anything, including a Word document or an MP3.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(myfield as numeric(18,6)) as myfield from mytable.
```

Comment: Error code -604, SQL state 42611: [SQL0604] Attributes not valid.